# Variable after the last associated handler

Tags: c++, function, try-catch

The following 3.3.3/2 quote:

> If the function has a function-try-block the potential scope of a
>   parameter or of a function-local predefined variable ends at the end
>   of the last associated handler, otherwise it ends at the end of the
>   outermost block of the function definition.

Consider the following example:

```
void foo()
{
    int a; //function-local predefined variable
    std::cin >> a;
    int z;
    try
    {
        z=5/a;
        std::cout << z << "\n";

    }
    catch(std::logic_error e)
    {
        std::cout << "Division by zero";
    } //end of the last associated handler
    std::cout << a; //a is still visible
}
```

Why `a` is still visible after the last associated handler?

Comment: You don't have a function-try-block there. Normal rules apply.

Comment: @Mat Can you post answer with example of apllying this rule?

Answer (score 1):

A function try-block looks like this:

```
void f()
try
{
    // Some code that might throw
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    // Exception caught
}
```

What you have is a normal function with a normal try-catch block inside of it.

When a function is defined like this, it's quite obvious that variables declared in the function (that is, declared in side the `try` block) will not exist outside of the `try` block.

Comment: Where is the function body in that case?

Comment: @Dmitrii It's the `try` block that is the "normal" function body, but also the `catch` block, though both are separate blocks.

Comment: "will not exist outside of the `try-catch` construct" - you can explicitly point it in your answer, as "(...) otherwise it ends at the end of the outermost block of the function definition" and in this case block associated with `catch` is the outermost.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a function-try-block which has a form of:

```
int f()
try {
    // ... logic
}
catch ( /* exception specification */) {
    // handle errors
}
```

In your case of an ordinary function the body of the function is from { to }:

```
void foo()
{
    // body
}
```